# MySQL Select Count with EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, select, exists

I have 3 tables.

**table1**
id, thing_id

**table_index**
id

**table_index_info**
table_index_id, table1_id

table_index_info contains a history of table_index. This history can refer to table1, possibly many times or 0 times.

I need to run a query that returns all rows in table1 with a specific thing_id.
It also needs to count how many rows in table_index that have at least 1 table_index_info linking to table1.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT table1.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(i.id)
      FROM table_index i
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 0
                 FROM table_index_info h
                 WHERE h.table1_id = table1.id
                 AND h.table_index_id = i.id)
   ) AS indexCount

FROM table1
WHERE table1.thing_id= $thingId
```

Is this the best/correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a JOIN instead of EXISTS in this case.

```
SELECT table1.*,
    ( SELECT COUNT(i.id)
         FROM table_index i
         INNER JOIN table_index_info h ON h.table_index_id = i.id 
         WHERE h.table1_id = table1.id
     ) AS indexCount
FROM table1
WHERE table1.thing_id = $thingId
```

Comment: Wouldn't a JOIN be slower if there are many many results on table_index_info?

Comment: I just ran a few tests and they both work BUT when there are a LOT of rows in the table_index_info the EXISTS query takes forever and the JOIN query is fast.. Can you explain this for me?